# How to play hls content without saving the file as .m3u8?

Tags: php, amazon-cloudfront, m3u8, signed-url

I'm using PHP code to retrieve the content of .m3u8 with a Signed URL from AWS CloudFront.

I can't be able to play the chunk .ts files inside it since you need also to sign their URL.

So, using PHP code, I re-write the contents of .m3u8

```
<?php
    $resourceKey = 'https://abcdefg.cloudfront.net/abcdef-1234.MOV_1000k*';
    $expires = time() + 172800;
    $customPolicy = <<<POLICY
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Resource": "{$resourceKey}",
            "Condition": {
                "DateLessThan": {"AWS:EpochTime": {$expires}}
            }
        }
    ]
}
POLICY;
    $signedUrl = $cloudFrontClient->getSignedUrl([
        'url' => $resourceKey,
        'policy' => $customPolicy,
        'private_key' => public_path().'/pk-ABCDEFGHIJ.pem',
        'key_pair_id' => 'ABCDEFGHIJ'
    ]);
    $signedUrl = str_replace('*', '.m3u8', $signedUrl);

    // get contents of the file and the query string
    $content = file_get_contents($signedUrl);
    parse_str(parse_url($signedUrl)['query'], $params);
    $qs = "?Policy=".$params['Policy']."&Signature=".$params['Signature']."&Key-Pair-Id=".$params['Key-Pair-Id'];

    // rewriting process
    $replaceThis = array(".m3u8", ".ts");
    $withThisValue = array(".m3u8".$qs, ".ts".$qs);
    $content = str_replace($replaceThis, $withThisValue, $content);
?>
```

I was able to sign the .ts inside the .m3u8 file. But the problem now is that, how can I convert `$content` to something playable to HTML5 video with VideoJS without downloading the file contents using file_put_contents? I don't want to save it on the directory. Just to convert it on blob data or decode it and play it Something like this. Is this possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Site</title>
</head>
<body>

    <video id='hls-example' class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source src="<?php echo $content; ?>" type="application/x-mpegURL">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>
    <script>
        var player1 = videojs('hls-example');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: I tried AWS Lambda Edge. But, it doesn't work when there are many chunk .ts inside the m3u8 file. It returns an error that exceeds the Viewer Request Quota of 40KB.

Comment: You could `echo $content;` in your first file and in the html you write `src="/first-file.php"`

Comment: Not relevant, but when you open the question link in chrome with hls player extension, it will always open in hls player because it has m3u8 in url at last.

Comment: @VPC, what do you mean `Not relevant`?

Comment: Thanks @RolandStarke for the idea, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @JSN Not relevant to the question

Comment: I don't get this explanation of yours `but when you open the question link in chrome with hls player extension, it will always open in hls player because it has m3u8 in url at last.`